# Why my app on heroku crash after 30 seconds?

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, discord, discord.js

I created a discord bot on discord.js and it works perfectly when i run it on local. But when i start this bot on Heroku after ~30s it's crashing with line in logs:

```
State changed from starting to crashed
```

I did some research and i didn't find solution.

All logs:

```
2020-05-07T14:57:21.053472+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-07T14:57:21.053500+00:00 app[web.1]: > discord-bort@0.0.1 start /app
2020-05-07T14:57:21.053501+00:00 app[web.1]: > node .
2020-05-07T14:57:21.053501+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-07T14:57:22.663961+00:00 app[web.1]: Online!
2020-05-07T14:58:18.856622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Please help and also sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what else is in your heroku logs?

Comment: @DanO info that says bot is online

Comment: You should always post the entire log regardless if you deem them relevant or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hundred percent sure but I think that you dont have a Procfile

```
// Procfile

worker: node index.js
```

^ Procfile must have a captial `.Procfile`

then head over to your application on heroku and if you have done it correctly you should see this in your resources tab
[image]

Should Read:

https://medium.com/@mason.spr/hosting-a-discord-js-bot-for-free-using-heroku-564c3da2d23f

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Links:

https://github.com

https://heroku.com